# using pandas HTML to read and print data from a website

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem:**

I need to make a code that lists off data from a online web data set with pandas pd.read_HTML then call out a temperature based on that list and have it display that row of data with a few parameters.

The trouble is the final part I need to make it to where it loops for when the user input is out of range or not == to one of the documented temperatures it returns a retry command a message saying something like invalid input

**What I have tried:**

I tried running it through a while loop, try except commands and if and elif but I'm sure I did it wrong because it almost all the time breaks my spyder program so I have to close it and try again.

Any recommendation or solutions would be super helpful cause I'm past the point of vague hints that supposed to lead me to an answer but leave me more confused.

**My code:**

````
def get_t_data(t):
    t_table = pd.read_html('https://thermo.pressbooks.com/chapter/saturation-properties-temperature-table/', header=0)
    t_df = t_table[0]
    data_df =t_df.loc[t_df['Temp'] == t]
    df_result = data_df[['Pressure', 'Volume ()', 'Energy (kJ/kg)', 'Enthalpy (kJ/kg)', 'Entropy (kJ/kg.K)']]
    df_final = df_result.to_string(index=False)
    return df_final


user_t = input('Please enter the temp you will like to research: ')
print('\n')

data = get_t_data(user_t)
print('For temperature {}°C your outputs are \n'.format(user_t))
print(data)```
````

Comment: so there's a good chance people are going to vote to close this because of the way your question is written. If that happens. definitely try reddit.com/r/learnprogramming or reddit.com/r/learnpython. They're a little more welcoming :)

Answer (score -1):

[upd]
something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_t_data(t):
    t_table = pd.read_html('https://thermo.pressbooks.com/chapter/saturation-properties-temperature-table/', header=0)
    t_df = t_table[0]

    t_df = t_df.iloc[1:,:] # to skip additional line of header

    ind = list(t_df['Temp'].astype(float))  # get all indexes as float as you have not only integer (0.01 and 373.95)
    if float(t) not in ind:  # check if the 't' in index
        return {'exist': False, 'result':'no such temp'}

    data_df =t_df.loc[t_df['Temp'] == t]
    df_result = data_df[['Pressure', 'Volume ()', 'Energy (kJ/kg)', 'Enthalpy (kJ/kg)', 'Entropy (kJ/kg.K)']]
    df_final = df_result.to_string(index=False)
    return {'exist': True, 'result': df_final}



# data format for get_t_data response
data = {'exist': False, 'result':''}



while data['exist'] == False:
    user_t = input('Please enter the temp you will like to research: ')
    print('\n')

    data = get_t_data(user_t)
    print('For temperature {}°C your outputs are \n'.format(user_t))
    print(data['result'])
```

Comment: this makes way more sense now from what i was attempting with the if command, i was trying to make it its own function which makes sense why the 2 wouldn't communicate. i ran this code and its exactly what i needed, thank you for explaining it